# Deployment can't be scheduled in Azure DevOps

Tags: azure-devops

Release pipelines don't allow us to schedule one-off releases.
can schedule releases on a regular cadence but that doesn't meet the requirement.

In short, looking for option (currently we have approve) where deployer can choose when to hit to prod.

Comment: Hi @maestromani, how are things going? Are the explanations and suggestions in my answer helpful to you? If you have any question about this, feel free to tell me.

Comment: Hi @BrightRan-MSFT, Thanks much for the reply. Appreciate it. My question is how do I schedule deployment to Prod ? After build, My release kick starts and deploys to dev followed up with approval to QA. My question is, after QA I want developer to schedule time to Prod and it should hit the prod on scheduled time. This should happen for every release pipeline, after QA, Developer have to key in the time .

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 types of scheduled trigger on release pipeline:

1. **[Scheduled release triggers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/triggers?view=azure-devops#scheduled-release-triggers):** Triggers a new release at specific times.

   If you want to trigger a release at a specific time instead of every build triggers a release, you can use the **Scheduled release triggers** and disable [**Continuous deployment triggers**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/triggers?view=azure-devops#continuous-deployment-triggers). With this way, by default the scheduled release will always use the latest build artifacts for deployments.

   In addition, if you have enabled the option "**Only schedule releases if the source or pipeline has changed**", after previous scheduled release, the release will be triggered at the specific times only when the source or the pipeline definition has updated. Otherwise, the release will not be triggered even if the specific times reach. If you want the scheduled release will be always triggered at the specific times, you can disable this option.

   [image]
2. **[Scheduled stage triggers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/triggers?view=azure-devops#stage-triggers):** Trigger a new deployment to the stage at a specific time, after a new release is triggered (**`After release`**), or the dependent previous stages are completed (**`After stage`**) in the release.

   When the scheduled deployment to the stage is triggered at the specific time, the deployment will use the build artifacts that triggered the current release, not always the latest build artifacts.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution is to have Pre-deployment approvement where you can later defer Release and specifiy exact date for the deployment.

[image: Azure Devops Defer Release]